# what is the max possible combinations of 1 2 3 4 5 6 without repeating

Tags: probability

Each number has to be used and only once in each set.

I don't know how to put it but it can't cycle . here is my example

123456
Is the same as 
234561
Same as 
345612

This isn't for any homework or anything it's something that's been bugging me, I came up with 48 combinations but I feel that's wrong

Comment: $\dfrac{6!}{6}=5!=120$?

Comment: But isn't that including the exclusion I mentioned?

Comment: The cycle exclusion is taken into account in the division by $6$.

Comment: Oh I see! Thank you very much. I had to Google because I didn't know what the symbols meant, to clarify to make sure I understand 1x2x3x4x5x6/6 = 1x2x3x4x5 = 120? And is this the definition of permutation?

Comment: The number of ways to seat 6 people at the round table. By rotating each person you get the same seating. Hence $\frac{6!}{6}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are asking about is the number of totally non-cyclic permutations of $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\} = A$. As the comments noted, this is the same as the seating arrangements.

> We note that there are $$6! = 720 $$ permutations of these objects. However, this clearly over-counts, because each arrangement of letters has $6$ symmetric, equivalent orderings. Thus, there are $720/6 = 120$ total.

Comment: You should remove the word other from the penultimate sentence.  If there were $6$ other orderings, there would be $7$ equivalent orderings of each $6$-cycle.