# Is there an equation to find out how after $\frac{6!}{6}$ to locate clockwise increase in numbers in sets of 2

Tags: probability, combinatorics

So I asked this question last night

[what is the max possible combinations of 1 2 3 4 5 6 without repeating](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1651737/what-is-the-max-possible-combinations-of-1-2-3-4-5-6-without-repeating)

And as stated I don't know what symbols mean, but I learned what $!$ is and how it works and how the solution is determined.

So now that I have 120 combinations I need to reduce it more.

Example we are using is hexagon because it has 6 sides. 
To reduce the amount of combinations I decided the hex into 3 parts set of 2 sides will have 2 numbers 1-6.

The rule I am trying to use to reduce possibilities each set has to increase in clockwise

Examples:

Yes 
12 34 56 
24 15 36 
45 13 24

No 
21 43 65 
32 54 61 
61 52 43

Is there a formula to use to figure this out?

Comment: You refer to hexagons for some reason.  Do you consider the following the same or different?  `12 34 56` and `34 56 12`?  What about `12 34 56` and `12 56 34`?

Comment: As for the previous question I linked to, they cannot rotate which makes 12 34 56  and 34 56 12 the same, but 12 56 34 and 12 34 56 okay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that as in the previous problem, you consider arrangements gained from rotational symmetry to be the same as one another (e.g. `12 34 56` is considered the same as `34 56 12` is considered the same as `56 12 34`), let us look at the problem in the following way.

We wish to partition the set $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ as subsets $A$, $B$, $C$, with each of size two, and $A,B,C$ considered distinct.

- Pick which two numbers go to set $A$.  This can be accomplished in $\binom{6}{2}=\frac{6!}{2!4!}=\frac{6\cdot 5}{2}=15$ ways.
- Pick which two numbers from those remaining go to set $B$.  This can be accomplished in $\binom{4}{2}=\frac{4!}{2!2!}=\frac{4\cdot 3}{2} = 6$ ways.
- Pick which two numbers from those remaining go to set $C$.  This can be accomplished in $\binom{2}{2}=\frac{2!}{2!0!}=1$ way.

For example, we partition as $A=\{1,3\}, B = \{2,4\}, C=\{5,6\}$

For each of these sets there is a **unique** way to arrange them in increasing order.

Now, we place the numbers from $A,B,C$ around the triangle (hexagon with paired sides?) and we notice that if we had done it as $ABC$ it is the "*same*" as though we did it $BCA$ or as $CAB$.  This implies that we accidentally counted every situation three times, so we divide by that amount to make it so we counted each situation exactly once.

Applying multiplication principle and dividing by symmetry, we get a final count of $\binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{2}\binom{2}{2}\cdot \frac{1}{3} = \frac{6!}{2!2!2!3}=\frac{15\cdot 6}{3}=\frac{90}{3}=30$.

---

For a generalization, supposing we have $2n$ numbers to arrange, $\{1,2,3,\dots,2n\}$, onto an $n$-gon with two numbers on each side, each side having the numbers appearing in increasing order clockwise where arrangements gained from rotations are considered "the same," there will be a total of $\binom{2n}{2,2,2,\dots,2}\frac{1}{n}=\frac{(2n)!}{(2!)^n n}=\frac{(2n)!}{2^n n}$ arrangements.

---

To output every possible arrangement, the following pseudo-code should suffice:

Define $a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2,c_1,c_2$ as integers

Set $a_1=1$   (*this will allow us to avoid having to remove the excess that comes from doublecounting scenarios*)

For $a_2=2..6$

..For $b_1=2..6$

....For $b_2=(b_1+1)..6$

......If $b_2=a_2$, skip

......For $c_1=2..6$

........If $c_1=b_2, c_1=b_1,$ or $c_1=a_2$, skip

........For $c_2=(c_1+1)..6$

..........If $c_2=b_2, c_2=b_1,$ or $c_2=a_2$ skip

..........Else, output $a_1a_2~~b_1b_2~~c_1c_2$

By skip, I mean end the current iteration of the loop and skip ahead to the next value.

Comment: I understand now, thank you very much, how would one print the 30 results?

Comment: @Itzawierdo pseudocode added above.  If my notation doesn't make sense, feel free to ask.

Comment: I am a little lost, my knowledge is minimal, I am doing my best to understand ,i understand the equation but not the code.

Comment: @Itzawierdo All it is essentially saying is, "run through every possible list of values for $a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2,c_1,c_2$ such that $a_1=1$, $a_2>a_1$, $b_2>b_1$, $c_2>c_1$, and there are no duplicates.

Comment: Thank you so much this was of great help!